# EF Core SQLite Function

Tags: function, sqlite

Does Entity Framework Core have an equivalent to the EF6 attribute

[SQLiteFunction(FuncType = FunctionType.Collation, Name = "RMNOCASE")]

to add a function to SQLite?

Answer (score 0):

This results in the desired action.

```
    public RootsMagicContext(string databasePath)
    {
        var connectionString = $"Data Source={databasePath}";
        this.connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionString);
        this.connection.CreateCollation("RMNOCASE", (s1, s2) => string.Compare(s1, s2, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
    {
        options.UseSqlite(this.connection);
    }
```